# eBPF: How can the sockaddr struct be read when hooking into security_socket_connect

Tags: c, linux-kernel, bpf, ebpf, bcc-bpf

As proposed in the presentation [Security Monitoring with eBPF](http://www.brendangregg.com/Slides/BSidesSF2017_BPF_security_monitoring.pdf) I'm trying to hook into [security_socket_connect](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/include/linux/security.h#L1218).

While my [gobpf](https://github.com/iovisor/gobpf)/[bcc](https://github.com/iovisor/bcc) based code partly works, I seem not be able to read the IP address in the `sockaddr` struct.

The relevant part looks like this:

```
int security_socket_connect_entry(struct pt_regs *ctx, struct socket *sock, struct sockaddr *address, int addrlen)
{    
    u32 address_family = address->sa_family;
    if (address_family == AF_INET) {
        struct ipv4_data_t data4 = {.pid = pid};

        struct sockaddr_in *addr2 = (struct sockaddr_in *)address;
```

After that I try to read the IP address in addr2. The first try was:

```
data4.daddr = addr2->sin_addr.s_addr;
```

The second try was with `bpf_probe_read`:

```
bpf_probe_read(&data4.daddr, sizeof(data4.daddr), (void *)((long)addr2->sin_addr.s_addr));
```

Both options present the same error:

```
R9 invalid mem access 'inv'

HINT: The invalid mem access 'inv' error can happen if you try to dereference memory without first using bpf_probe_read() to copy it to the BPF stack. Sometimes the bpf_probe_read is automatic by the bcc rewriter, other times you'll need to be explicit.
```

A repo with a buildable sample can be found here: [socket-connect-bpf](https://github.com/p-/socket-connect-bpf)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out thanks to [an answer to issue #1858](https://github.com/iovisor/bcc/issues/1858#issuecomment-400402655) in the [bcc repo](https://github.com/iovisor/bcc).

We have to operate on the pointer, so the IP address can be read like this:

```
bpf_probe_read(&data4.daddr, sizeof(data4.daddr), &addr2->sin_addr.s_addr);
```